# growing apk file size

Tags: android, build, apk, filesize

It appears that each time I export to apk in eclipse the file is getting ~ half a meg bigger. I am making minor code edits so this large a difference shouldn't be happening. Has this happened for anyone else?

Comment: This may happen if your APK is exported in the /res directory of your project, each time under a different name. In which case each time you do an export, the old versions of your APK will be included to the new distribution.

Comment: Ah i See, this is probably the problem I had it in an assets folder for the project. Thanks! If you make that into an answer I'll up-vote and accept it.

Comment: Thank you! I've moved it to an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may happen if your APK is exported in the `/res` or `/asset` directory of your project, each time under a different name. In which case each time you do an export, the old versions of your APK will be included to the new distribution.

Answer (score -5):

no its not serious matter, i have also same thing but as your resource and you code are longer it will became large.i refer to you that if you working with high resolution & lots of graphics then use server to store data.